# Define exception error in python NameError

Tags: python

I am trying the following code in python

```
def fixPdf(pdfFile):
    try:
        fileOpen = file(pdfFile, "a")
        fileOpen.write("%%EOF")
        fileOpen.close()
        return "Fixed"
    except:
        return "Unable to open file: %s with error: %s" % (pdfFile, str(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fixPdf('Sample.pdf')
```

I got the error `NameError: name 'e' is not defined`. How can I define this variable in the exception part of the code?

Comment: You just need to change `except:` to `except Exception as e:` since `e` is not defined in your code

Comment: Did you copy the code from somewhere? Where was `e` defined there?

Comment: [Never use a bare except](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54948581/6298712)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intent is for `e` to be the exception, you need to assign it to that name as part of the `except`:

```
def fixPdf(pdfFile):
    try:
        fileOpen = file(pdfFile, "a")
        fileOpen.write("%%EOF")
        fileOpen.close()
        print("Fixed")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unable to open file: {pdfFile} with error: {e}")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fixPdf('Sample.pdf')
```

You also need to `print` the messages if you want them to be visible, since the caller does not print the return value of the function.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got now an error `Unable to open file: Sample.pdf with error: name 'file' is not defined`

Comment: Sounds like you haven't defined or imported whatever this `file` thing is that's supposed to open the PDF file.  Maybe you meant to use the `open` function?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works now but when manually open the pdf after executing the code, I received a message to save the file. Can I save the pdf file with the same code?

Comment: Debugging the PDF formatting and/your PDF viewer is out of my wheelhouse, unfortunately :\